# Manipulate binding attribute in Angular 2 with jQuery

Tags: jquery, angular

I have an element that has attribute binding like this:

`<div id='myDiv' [attr.data-url]='url'></div>`

Am I able to detect the changes of `url` if I use some jQuery code to manipulate that `attribute`, something like:

`$('#myDiv').attr('data-url', 'example.com');`

I have looked at some other questions but there is no answer that I'm looking for.

PS: If I change `data-url` attribute with jQuery, `url` variable will change accordingly, or not? If not, does that mean we cannot be able to change `[attr.data-url]` after all? I'm so confused right now.

Comment: I find the question quite confusing. Did you actually try it and it did not work or didn't you not try yet? I guess it will not work (not sure though).

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: I've just thought of it as a solution and not tried it yet. Maybe I'm not specific, but my question is how to detect changes that happen to a binding attribute if I use jQuery(not native angular 2) to manipulate it.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: Can we be able to detect changes of attributes of any elements? Or it's only possible for `input`?